# Best way of storing Strings to be accessible through ADB shell

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to store Phone States in a certain way so that I can view it through an ADB shell environment **as the app is running**. I'm a beginner to Android development, so take it easy on me!

What I have in mind/what's going on:

- The data will thus be very simple (just Strings)
- I'm thinking of using an SQLite 3 database since ADB allows you to manipulate and view it through a shell.

Some questions:

- Will I be able to access the data while the app is running? Basically I want the app to store the strings as the state changes, and using a wrapper tool someone else wrote to execute the query in real-time (and do other things independent of Android using the result of that query).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can store strings even in plain text files instead of SQLite. It depends on the purpose of these data.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I've already decided to just use plain text files for simplicity.